# Array problems in C: Do I need to pass a single array cell back to my global array by reference in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, pass-by-pointer

I am manipulating the row and column within a user-defined function called dropmove, and I am currently stuck on the method of passing and returning the array cell/value into my global array. I am getting conflicting results on how I need to return the cell. Do I need to call a pointer, or can I pass it by value since it is a single cell? If I want to manipulate my row and column value later on, will pass-by value fail to return the value of the cell row and col?

From what I tried in the past, it has seemed to be hit or miss. In one test, I saw that I printed the cell values in the correct orientation. That gives me some rest, but I want absolute surety that I am going down the right path.

Here is a minimal portion of my code below.

```
int row;
int column;
int myrowcol[8][8] = {{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                     {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
                     };

int dropmove()
{
 mycol[row][column] = selectPlayer();
 column = column;
  for (int row = 0; row <= 7; row ++)
    {
       if (row == 0 || myrowcol[row + 1][column] != 0)
       {
         myrowcol[row][column] = selectPlayer();
         if (myrowcol[row][column] == 0)
         {
          column = 0;
         }
         return myrowcol[row][column];
       }
       
    }  
}

int main()
{
   dropmove();
}
```

Comment: An assignment like `column = column` does nothing. What are you really trying to do there?

Comment: Also, `myrowcol[row + 1]` will be out of bounds when `row == 7`.

Comment: `if (myrowcol[row][column] == 0)` will never happen because you have an unconditional `return` before it. And speaking of `return`, if the loop ends without your explicit `return` statement, what value does the function return then?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have another user-defined function that this relies on. I didn't want to use up too much space. My only question is this: do I need to use pass by reference or pass by pointer as compared to what I have been doing, pass by value?

Comment: What is the function supposed to do? Is it supposed to return a single `int` value? Then return that single `int` value as a value rather than a pointer to it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's supposed to return the cell location and the int value that results. I want to update the array I initialized with the cell location/value. I want to update the main 8x8 array.

Comment: So you want to return multiple values? Then either use a structure that you can return. Or pass pointers to the variables as arguments, like `int dropmove(int *newrow, int *newcol)`